# My Spark job is deleting the target folder inside hdfs

Tags: scala, file, csv, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a script that writes Hive table content into a CSV file in HDFS.
The target folder name is given in a JSON paramater file. When I launch the script I notice that the folder that I already created is deleted automatically and then an error is thrown saying that the target file does not exist. This my script:

```
sigma.cache // sigma is the df that contains the hive table. Tested OK
sigma.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("csv").option("header", true).option("delimiter", "|").save(Parametre_vigiliste.cible)
val conf = new Configuration()
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
//Parametre_vigiliste.cible is the variable inide the JSON file that contains the target folder name
val file = fs.globStatus(new Path(Parametre_vigiliste.cible + "/part*"))(0).getPath().getName(); 
fs.rename(new Path(Parametre_vigiliste.cible + "/" + file), new Path(Parametre_vigiliste.cible + "/" + "FIC_PER_DATALAKE_.txt"));
sigma.unpersist()
```

ERROR THROWN:

> exception caught: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data
>   source does not support null data type.

Can this code delete a folder for a certain reason? Thank you.

Comment: Try changing your save mode from overwrite to append so `SaveMode.Overwrite` to `SaveMode.Append`

Comment: Already tried. Same problem..

Comment: With `sigma.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("csv").option("header", true).option("delimiter", "|").save(Parametre_vigiliste.cible)`, are you sure that the output file is not empty? I don't think spark will write an empty df to the output location which may be way it is being overwritten with no file found.

Comment: could you please run **sigma.printSchema** and check the column types. Can this code delete a folder for a certain reason ? Yes, It will  because of SaveMode.Overwrite.  whether job succeeded or not destination folder will be recreated once it sees Overwrite.

Comment: @Zack The output file is initially inexistant. I want the script to create it.

Prateek printSchema returns: root and then all my df columns: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Certain collumns are: null (nullable=true) is that a problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Prateek suggested I tried `sigma.printSchema` and I discovered some null columns. I rectified that and it worked.